# unordered_map <(int or string), MyClass> How to access and print elements of MyClass

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>


using namespace std;

class Token {
    string strVar;
    int intVar;
    bool boolVar;

public:
    Token(string strVar, int intVar ,bool boolVar):
        strVar(strVar), intVar(intVar) ,boolVar(boolVar){
    }

    string getStrVar()  {return this->strVar;}
    int getIntVar()     {return this->intVar;}
    bool getBoolVar()   {return this->boolVar;}

};

int main(){
    unordered_map<int , int> mymap;
        //I WANT -> unordered_map<int , Token> mymap;

    mymap[1]= 11;
        //I WANT -> // mymap[1] = Token("string1", 1, true);
    mymap[2]= 12;
        //I WANT -> // mymap[2] = Token("string2", 2, false);
    mymap[3]= 13;
        //I WANT -> //mymap[3] = Token("string3", 3, true);

    int tk = mymap[1];
        //I WANT -> //Token tk = mymap[1];
    mymap[3] = tk;

    for (auto& x: mymap) {
        cout << x.first << ": " << x.second << endl;
        //I WANT -> print all Var from MyClass,
        //for example, x.second.getStrVar() << x.second.getIntVar() << x.second.getBoolVar() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Atual OUTPUT:

```
3: 11 
2: 12
1: 11
```

As I explained in the comments, how can I use the unordered_map<> function with my class and loop through your elements so that I can use the methods of the class???

I need this output:

```
string1 1 true
string2 2 true
string1 1 true
```

Comment: You should be able to do it more or less as you have done in the commented-out parts. What exactly is the problem you're having when you try it that way?

Comment: @SeanBurton When i run i got this following error:

          for (auto& x: mymap) {
XXX        cout << x.first << ": " << x.second << endl;
          }
45| error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'|

And sometimes open an archive "/include/tuple"

C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\tuple|1102|error: no matching function for call to 'Token::Token()'|

Comment: Can you post the full and exact code that is actually producing the error...

Comment: @SeanBurton its https://pastebin.com/EEZ62Lf0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map type argument must be default-constructible. That means, you need to declare default constructor for your class Token.

EDIT
Well, not exactly map type argument, but the operator[] argument of Map as it's specified [here on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at).

Moreover, to print it out in a loop you need to define an output operator (operator<<) for your class.

Your working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Token {
    string strVar{};
    int intVar{};
    bool boolVar{};

public:

    Token() {};

    Token(string strVar, int intVar ,bool boolVar):
        strVar(strVar), intVar(intVar) ,boolVar(boolVar){
    }

    string getStrVar()  {return this->strVar;}
    int getIntVar()     {return this->intVar;}
    bool getBoolVar()   {return this->boolVar;}

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Token& rhs) {
        out << rhs.strVar;
    }

};

int main(){
        //unordered_map<int , int> mymap;
        //I WANT -> //
    unordered_map<int , Token> mymap;

        //mymap[1]= 11;
        //I WANT -> //
    mymap[1] = Token("string1", 1, true);
        //mymap[2]= 12;
        //I WANT -> //
    mymap[2] = Token("string2", 2, false);
        //mymap[3]= 13;
        //I WANT -> //
    mymap[3] = Token("string3", 3, true);

        //int tk = mymap[1];
        //I WANT -> //
    Token tk = mymap[1];
    mymap[3] = tk;

    for (auto& x: mymap) {
        cout << x.first << ": " << x.second << endl;
        //I WANT -> print all Var from MyClass,
        //for example, x.second.getStrVar() << x.second.getIntVar() << x.second.getBoolVar() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With default constructor the code compiles https://ideone.com/s0LTcf but I can't find why default constructor is needed. `std::unordered_map meets the requirements of Container, AllocatorAwareContainer, UnorderedAssociativeContainer.` and in none of them I see that requirement.

Comment: But I already have a constructor, right? Like: Token(string strVar, int intVar ,bool boolVar):
        strVar(strVar), intVar(intVar) ,boolVar(boolVar){
    }

@Caribou

What do you mean "to define operator"?

Comment: @MateuszDrost I edited my answer with litte clarification and link to cppreference, where it's  precisely explained.

Comment: @Guttizin Yes, you defined a **custom constructor**, thus disabling the automatically generated **default constructor** (the one with no arguments), so you need to be specific and define it again.

Comment: Got it, Thanks!! @MateuszDrost and Caribou
A 'simple' solution but it took me a long time. Btw why operator is needed? It runs without it.

Comment: @Guttizin Ok, I see now that default constructor is not needed if instead of `operator[]` are used methods `insert` and `at` https://ideone.com/FPVb03

Comment: @Guttizin Output operator let's you output class with simple o << x.second call, instead of iterating over getter functions (like o << x.second.getStr() <<
 x.second.getInt() )